# Flutter: font_awesome_icon pro version give error ? How can i set path of font_awesome cloned repo?

Tags: flutter, font-awesome, pubspec

I didn't understand how to give the path of the pro version in the current project

I read the setup from pub.dev but don't know how can I did it.

1. followed this steps : [setup information](https://pub.dev/packages/font_awesome_flutter#setup)
2. already clone a repo

[image]

> facing one error here : `zsh: permission denied: ./configurator.sh`.    while running this ./configurator.sh it will show error.

3. how to give path of new font repo to my project? ( in pubspec.yaml)

   [image]

> here is image where i stored clone repo project
> [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using MAC / M1 chip then use this command to run the file

```
$ cd util
$ bash ./configurator.sh --dynamic
```

To exclude unused styles combine the configurator options:

```
$ configurator.sh --dynamic --exclude solid
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$ sudo ./configurator.sh --exclude solid
$ sudo ./configurator.sh --exclude solid,brands
```

Give the Access to the Path

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you can use the absolute path here. But you can use the relative path to target package here.

**For relative path:**

Add the package somewhere in your project. Usually, all local repositories are stored in new `packages` folder at the root of the project (where the lib folder is located)

You'll get something like: `./packages/package_folder`

**For absolute path:**

Copy the path to the package folder. You'll get something like `Users/username/Desktop/../package_folder`

Comment: Yes After the proper path and running this command works perfectly. sudo ./configurator.sh --exclude solid